# MySQL query - how to get relevant answer from table with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have one table with 3 columns where each of them is just foreign key referencing some other tables.

My question is how to get relevant results.

I do know I am looking for some sort of **JOIN**, just I do not know which one and how to do that.

Here are my tables:

**Member_table** with: id (int), member_firstname(varchar)

**Category_table** with: id(int), category(varchar)

and finally:

**Relationship_table** with: id(int), FK_member_id1, FK_category_id, FK_member_id2.

What I do need is simply query the **Relationship** table to get actually names, for example:

**"first member with name ABC relates to/has category with second member with name DEF".**

Thanx a lot for your time in advance.

Comment: updated  you question ... add   a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: You are looking for [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).